# Glassfish not closing threads when done request

Tags: java, linux, servlets, glassfish-3

I have a Java Servlet that has a doPost method and when the doPost finishes, I assumed Glassfish would close the connection, but I was wrong. The Servlet is on a Linux server and after 300 posts the thread count returned:

```
ps -eLFU glassfish | grep domain1 | wc -l
362
```

Before any posts, the thread count was 72. The responses are all successful but I do not understand why Glassfish is not closing the connections. I am using the default configurations for Glassfish.

The reason I am trying to solve this problem is when my servlet is being hit at some point I get this error on the Linux server:

```
su: cannot set user id: Resource temporarily unavailable
```

In the /etc/security/limits.conf I have this:

```
glassfish hard nproc 4192
glassfish soft nproc 2024
```

I do not want to update the limits.conf  but instead try to make sure it does not reach those numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem it was a code issue. The servlet uses a client to make a call to a web service and the client needed to be a singleton. Originally I was creating a client per POST to the servlet, which created a lot of threads under glassfish. Once I made the client a singleton the thread count went down a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Is glassfish keeping the connection open? or the thread running? They are different things.  Threads might be started, and not shutdown to service new connections in the future.  That's standard behavior. Can you take a thread dump using "kill -3 PID", where PID is the process id of the glassfish process? This will dump all of the running thread to standard output, and you can see what each thread is doing.  There you'll be able to see if it's stuck in your code or waiting for a new connection. You can find more info [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19879-01/821-0177/abgax/index.html) on how to get a thread dump.

Comment: After the 300 posts. I tried the kill -3 PID and it returned nothing. Also it is the threads because ps -L shows the threads for a process.

Comment: Also tried kill -3 PID while it is running doing posts and it shows nothing.

Comment: Are you checking the standard output for the glassfish process? This is normally piped to a log file (server.log by default if I remember correctly).

Comment: No I was not looking in server.log. Thanks I will try that and get back to you. :)

Comment: No deadlocks. I got a lot of these:

Thread "pool-309-thread-1" thread-id: 289 thread-state: WAITING Waiting on lock: java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject@75991e ...

Started from 1.

Comment: Thanks, I think I am going to lower down Glassfish settings to not reach the limit that is set on the Linux server.